# Accessing dataitem value in RadGrid_ItemDataBound event (dataItem["column"].Text is always empty)

Tags: c#, webforms, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I have a scenario where I have an item template with 2 controls (label and hyperlink) in it. Based on the type of data I am either going to hide/show the label/hyperlink. After doing research and even finding documentation on the Telerik site here is what I came up with and my .Text property is always an empty string so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Below is how I am binding my grid w/ a hardcoded DataTable. There is clearly a value for the MARK column in the first row "MARK" so I don't get why .Text is always empty.

```
protected void gridStudentGrade_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    //X axis column: "STUDENT"
    //Y axis column: "COURSE"
    //Z axis column: "GRADE"

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Course", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Student1", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Student2", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Student3", typeof(string));

    table.Rows.Add("", "MARK", "BRIAN", "ALEX");
    table.Rows.Add("MATH", 80, 95, 70);
    table.Rows.Add("SCIENCE", 55, 80, 72);
    table.Rows.Add("ENGLISH", 70, 85, 65);

    (sender as RadGrid).DataSource = table;
}


protected void gridStudentGrade_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;

        Label label1 = item.FindControl("label1") as Label;
        HyperLink hyperlink1 = item.FindControl("hyperlink1") as HyperLink;


        string student1= item["Student1"].Text;

        if (student1 == "MARK")
        {
            label1.Visible = true;
            hyperlink1.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            label1.Visible = false;
            hyperlink1.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you showed looks fine. However, you need to make sure that `AutoGenerateColumns` RadGrid property is set to `true`. So the markup of the grid would look like:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="gridStudentGrade" runat="server" 
    OnNeedDataSource="GridItems_NeedDataSource"
    OnItemDataBound="gridStudentGrade_ItemDataBound">
    AutoGenerateColumns="true"
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Comment: It was my mistake. I was actually trying to access the .Text value of a GridTemplateColumn... In this case I just have to find the control in the ItemTemplate and get the .Text property value of it.